# CSS - gradient "border" using classes

Tags: html, css, gradient

I'm working on a project, and I want the design to be "smooth". To achieve this, I'm using CSS gradient. However, I don't know exactly how to achieve what I want. My CSS code are as following:

```
#wrapper .midcontainer
{
 width: 1000px;
 margin: 20px auto;
}

#wrapper .midcontainer .mid
{
 width: 980px;
 background: #2d2929;
 position: relative;
}

#wrapper .midcontainer .mid .left
{
 background: #2d2929;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #2d2929, #e0e0e0);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #2d2929, #e0e0e0);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #2d2929, #e0e0e0);
 background: linear-gradient(right, #2d2929, #e0e0e0);
 width: 10px;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 left: -10px;
}

#wrapper .midcontainer .mid .right
{
 background: #2d2929;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2d2929, #e0e0e0);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #2d2929, #e0e0e0);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2d2929, #e0e0e0);
 background: linear-gradient(left, #2d2929, #e0e0e0);
 width: 10px;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 right: -10px;
}

#wrapper .midcontainer .mid .top
{
 background: #2d2929;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #2d2929, #e0e0e0);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #2d2929, #e0e0e0);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #2d2929, #e0e0e0);
 background: linear-gradient(bottom, #2d2929, #e0e0e0);
 width: 1000px;
 height: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 top: -10px;
 left: -10px;
 border-top-radius: 5px;
}

#wrapper .midcontainer .mid .bot
{
 background: #2d2929;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2d2929, #e0e0e0);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2d2929, #e0e0e0);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2d2929, #e0e0e0);
 background: linear-gradient(top, #2d2929, #e0e0e0);
 width: 1000px;
 height: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -10px;
 left: -10px;
 border-bottom-radius: 5px;
}
```

My HTML code is:

```
  <div class="midcontainer">
   <div class="mid">   
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bot"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />test<br />
    </div>
  </div>
```

My result is looking like this:
[image]

I want the edges to have a radius and intercept. I'm open to suggestions about developing this code differently. However, it's not looking really good in the edges. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Have you considered using a border-image? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

Comment: I have checked it out - however, I can't seem to get it to work with the border color corresponding (see image). I want the border to go from #2d2929 to #e0e0e0 around the whole box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use box-shadow to create a similar effect

```
<div class="shadow"> test </div>

div .shadow{
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px rgb(85, 85, 85);
}
```

A few modifications should get you exactly what you want.

Comment: You just beat me to it! I created this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QDff4/ ... I used two layered box shadows to recreate his image as closely as I could

Comment: Used it with the modification provided by Blake Mann. It's not the same thing, but it's similar.. :)

Answer (score 0):

answer is already given , **it is mainly about the gradients** as the question mentions them.

They can be used as multiple background and sized to be **[sprayed all around a box](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jdwgG)** and even **[be animated](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/IGliC)**.

If you use `background-image` and `box-shadow:inset x x x` , the shadow can cover the `background-image`.

---

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LvEBA)** with a single div , using:

- multiple gradients,
- shadow (as answered)
- or a mix of gradient and inset shadow